# Having an issue with Next without For error

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am trying to get the VBA macro to check if there is a certain value in a column, and then go through a series of commands in order to create an array of data. Based on whether or not the cell value is "MAF" or "MAM", it should do the operation. I tried to create an if then elseif then, but I keep on receiving the "next without for" error, even though I know there is a for at the start. I appreciate any help with this matter.

I'm including the whole code for posterity. The issue I am having is in the MAP section

```
Dim IncArray(1 To 25) As Variant
Dim DurArray(1 To 25) As Variant

Sub iteratePm()

    Dim premArray(1 To 27) As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim valdate As Date
    Dim lastPremCol, lastPremCol2 As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
    valdate = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", -1, DateAdd("d", 1, wb.Sheets("Info").Range("ValDt"))))
    Length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets("STD Detail Premium").Columns(2))
    l = 0
    n = 1
    
    wb.Sheets("P_Pm Summary 2").Cells.ClearContents
    
    wb.Sheets("P_Pm Summary 2").Cells(1, 1) = "Indicator"
    wb.Sheets("P_Pm Summary 2").Cells(1, 2) = "CTLNO"
    wb.Sheets("P_Pm Summary 2").Cells(1, 3) = "IncYrMth"
    wb.Sheets("P_Pm Summary 2").Cells(1, 4) = "Dur"
    wb.Sheets("P_Pm Summary 2").Cells(1, 5) = "Pm"
    
    
    Call getIncYrMth_Duration
    
    For i = 1 To 50
        If wb.Sheets("SPm").Cells(1, i) = valdate Then lastPremCol = i
    Next i
    
    lastPremCol2 = lastPremCol
    
    'index 1 is Indicator
    'index 2 is CTLNO
    'index 3-27 is premium, aligning to month 0, 1, 2,..., 25
    
    For i = 2 To Length
        'Indicator
        premArray(1) = wb.Sheets("SPm").Cells(i, 1)
        'CTLNO
        premArray(2) = wb.Sheets("SPm").Cells(i, 2)
        'If premArray(2) = 44028 Then Stop
        If premArray(2) = 41431 Then
            divisor = 5
        Else
            divisor = 1
        End If
        
100:    If premArray(2) = 44028 Then lastPremCol = lastPremCol - 3
        For j = 3 To 26
            If premArray(2) = 44028 Then
                If n = 1 Then
                    premArray(1) = "44028B"
                    premArray(j) = premArray(j) + wb.Sheets("Pm Summary").Cells(26, lastPremCol)
                ElseIf n = 2 Then
                    premArray(1) = "44028A"
                    premArray(j) = premArray(j) + wb.Sheets("Pm Summary").Cells(27, lastPremCol)
                End If
            Else
                premArray(j) = premArray(j) + wb.Sheets("SPm").Cells(i, lastPremCol)
            End If
            If j = 3 Then lastPremCol = lastPremCol + 1
            lastPremCol = lastPremCol - 1
        Next j

        If premArray(2) = 44028 Then n = n + 1
        'Dur25 premium = 0
        premArray(27) = 0
        lastPremCol = lastPremCol2
        If wb.Sheets("SPm").Cells(i, 2).Value <> wb.Sheets("SPm").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Or premArray(2) = 44028 Then
            'print results
            For m = 1 To divisor
                'Setting 41431 indicators
                If premArray(2) = 41431 Then
                    If m = 1 Then Indicator = "41431A"
                    If m = 2 Then Indicator = "41431B"
                    If m = 3 Then Indicator = "41431C"
                    If m = 4 Then Indicator = "41431D"
                    If m = 5 Then Indicator = "41431E"
                Else
                    Indicator = premArray(1)
                End If
                For k = 2 To 26
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 1) = Indicator
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2) = Format(CStr(premArray(2)), "00000")
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 3) = IncArray(k - 1)
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 4) = DurArray(k - 1)
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 5) = premArray(k + 1) / divisor 
                Next k
            'keep incrementing l because it is the row where data will get pasted, don't want to overwrite
            l = l + k - 2
            Next m
            'set to 0 for next CTLNO
            For j = 3 To 27
                premArray(j) = 0
            Next j
        End If
        If n <= 2 And premArray(2) = 44028 Then GoTo 100
        Do While wb.Sheets("SPrm").Cells(i, 2) = 44028 And wb.Sheets("SPm").Cells(i + 1, 2) = 44028
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next i
    
    Length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets("NPm").Columns(2))
    
    For i = 1 To 50
        If wb.Sheets("NPm").Cells(1, i) = valdate Then lastPremCol = i
    Next i
    
    lastPremCol2 = lastPremCol
    
    For i = 2 To Length
        'Indicator
        premArray(1) = "NL"
        'CTLNO
        premArray(2) = wb.Sheets("NPm").Cells(i, 1)
        For j = 3 To 26
            premArray(j) = premArray(j) + wb.Sheets("NPm").Cells(i, lastPremCol)
            If j = 3 Then lastPremCol = lastPremCol + 1
            lastPremCol = lastPremCol - 1
        Next j
        premArray(27) = 0
        lastPremCol = lastPremCol2

        If wb.Sheets("NPm").Cells(i, 1).Value <> wb.Sheets("NPm").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
            Indicator = premArray(1)
            For k = 2 To 26
                wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 1) = Indicator
                wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2) = Format(CStr(premArray(2)), "00000")
                wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 3) = IncArray(k - 1)
                wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 4) = DurArray(k - 1)
                wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 5) = premArray(k + 1) 
            Next k
            l = l + k - 2
            'set to 0 for next CTLNO
            For j = 3 To 27
                premArray(j) = 0
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    
   ** 'MAP Section
    Length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Columns(2))
    
    For i = 1 To 50
        If wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(1, i) = valdate Then lastPremCol = i
    Next i
    
    lastPremCol2 = lastPremCol
    
    For i = 2 To Length
        'check if MAF or MAM
        If wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i, 3).Value = "MAF" Then
            'Indicator
            premArray(1) = "MAF"
            'CTLNO
            premArray(2) = wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i, 1)
            For j = 3 To 26
                premArray(j) = premArray(j) + wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i, lastPremCol)
                If j = 3 Then lastPremCol = lastPremCol + 1
                lastPremCol = lastPremCol - 1
            Next j
            premArray(27) = 0
            lastPremCol = lastPremCol2

            If wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i, 1).Value <> wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
                'print results                Indicator = premArray(1)
                For k = 2 To 26
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 1) = Indicator
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2) = Format(CStr(premArray(2)), "00000")
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 3) = IncArray(k - 1)
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 4) = DurArray(k - 1)
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 5) = premArray(k + 1) 
                Next k

                l = l + k - 2
                
                For j = 3 To 27
                    premArray(j) = 0
                Next j
            End If
        ElseIf wb.Sheets("MAP Detail ").Cells(i, 3).Value = "MAM" Then
            'Indicator
            premArray(1) = "MAM"
            'CTLNO
            premArray(2) = wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i, 1)
            For j = 3 To 26
                premArray(j) = premArray(j) + wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i, lastPremCol)
                If j = 3 Then lastPremCol = lastPremCol + 1
                lastPremCol = lastPremCol - 1
            Next j
            premArray(27) = 0
            lastPremCol = lastPremCol2
            If wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i, 1).Value <> wb.Sheets("MAP Detail").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
                'print results
                Indicator = premArray(1)
                For k = 2 To 26
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 1) = Indicator
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 2) = Format(CStr(premArray(2)), "00000")
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 3) = IncArray(k - 1)
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 4) = DurArray(k - 1)
                    wb.Sheets("Pm Summary 2").Cells(k + l, 5) = premArray(k + 1)
                Next k
                l = l + k - 2
               
                For j = 3 To 27
                    premArray(j) = 0
                Next j
            End If
        Next i**
              
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    
    MsgBox "Done!"
    
End Sub
```

In the MAP section highlighted above, I was trying to get the program to see if a cell had either the MAF or MAM value, and then do the series of calculations. The last next i is the one that the debugger is saying that there is no "For", except it should be the first for.

Comment: As you are indenting your code correctly, it is easy to see: You are missing an `End If` before the `Next i`.

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you! That did seem to eliminate the error. However, it is only outputting MAM, not MAF. I am not sure why it still isn't separating those two

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow the exact logic of your program, nor do I have your data. I would suggest you use the debugger and step through the code to understand the behaviour.

Comment: could be because you have spaces after your sheet name in this line?         ElseIf wb.Sheets("MAP Detail ").Cells(i, 3).Value = "MAM" Then

Comment: @HannahW I believe that was a typing error as I was trying to anonymize the data, but thank you!!